# Layout UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, android-studio

In my recent android studio project I want to change the actual activity by using a button. The first Screen works well but if I am pressing the ChangeActivity Button the App stopps.

This is the Code of the Activity I want to open by the use of a button. I get the following error for line 12:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binary XML file line #0: >You must supply a layout_width attribute.
>                                                                             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:770)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:7034)
>                                                                              at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:7216)
>                                                                              at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams.(ConstraintLayout.java:1662)
>                                                                              at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:1223)
>                                                                              at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.generateLayoutParams(ConstraintLayout.java:383)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:860)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
>                                                                              at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
>                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
>                                                                              at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
>                                                                              at programms.texttoserver.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:12)
>                                                                              at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6720)
>                                                                              at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2673)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2781)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1508)
>                                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:241)
>                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6274)
>                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
>                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

So this was the error I get when pressing the button. So this is the code where I get the Error in Line 12.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Line 12 --> setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    }
}
```

And here is a part of the MainActivity with the ChangeAcitivity Button:

```
 btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class));
                }
        });
```

I have barely no Idea why this should not work so I would appreciate it if you could give me a hint what is wrong with my code.

Comment: `You must supply a layout_width attribute`, check that you have supplied a `layout_width`

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer